# Выборка записей, которые были добавлены не более суток назад

Tags: php, mysql, sql

с выводом записей за определённое число разобрался..

```
SELECT * FROM count WHERE date = 31.01.2017
```

Но как вывести записи, которые были добавлены не более суток назад?

UPD
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас точно MySQL? Или, может, формат поля `date` - текстовый?

Comment: @Akina обновил шапку

Comment: И вот именно показанный текст запроса - что-то выводит? тогда это инициатива используемого клиента - конечно, удобная, но услуга-то медвежья...

Comment: @Akina выводит, но все записи

Comment: `с выводом записей за определённое число разобрался..` `выводит, но все записи`... и даже добавить нечего.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Посмотрите документацию: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

```sql
SELECT * FROM count WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: что-то не так, формат записи в поле - 2017-04-26 20:52:26, если в условии брать >= то выводит вообще все записи, если изменять условия на <,=,<= то вообще ничего не выводит

Comment: Давайте разбираться. Покажите что у вас вообще содержится в таблице:
`SELECT * FROM count`

Comment: Обновил, посмотрите

Comment: Все логично. Посмотрите внимательно на свои данные. У вас две записи. Одна 26.04, вторая - 24.06. Запросом вы хотите получить все записи не старше суток, но они обе не старше суток, т.к. сейчас 24.04 (одна запись сегодняшним числом, вторая - послезавтра), по этому запрос выводит обе эти записи. Если вы поменяете логический оператор, все аналогично, ничего не вернется, т.к. у вас нет записей старше суток.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте [мануал](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html), станет понятнее, как работать с датами.

В MySQL есть `CURDATE()`, возвращает текущую дату (без времени, например, `2017-04-25`). Чтобы выбрать новые данные, начиная со вчерашнего дня, используйте запрос:

```
select *
from count
where date >= curdate() - interval 1 day
```

Если хотите получить данные, добавленные ровно за 24 часа, то используйте `NOW()`, который возвращает текущую дату + время:

```
select *
from count
where date >= now() - interval 1 day
```